# Form position on screen (FMX, Win32)

Tags: firemonkey, c++builder

I want to know where my form is on the screen.  I've looked at position properties (e.g. this->Top, this->Left etc.) but they don't seem to fit the bill.  I want to be able to determine how far my form is from the top/bottom of screen, and from left/right side of screen.

I'm using C++ Builder and FMX building a Win32 app.

thanks, russ

[image]

UPDATE 1:  Turns out that what i really need is to find that coordinate (X,Y) with respect to the entire Desktop, not just the primary monitor.  The Desktop spans multiple monitors.

Answer (score 1):

Your forms `Top` and `Left` properties should give you the position relative to the active desktops top left position but you may need to use `ClientToScreen`/`ScreenToClient` too. Seems to be hard to get the precise offset in FMX.

```
void __fastcall TForm1::MoveToTopLeft()
{
    TPointF cli(0.0, 0.0);
    TPointF sp = ClientToScreen(cli);

    Left -= sp.x;
    Top = 0;
}
```

There's something very asymmetrical with that solution ...

Comment: Thanks Ted.  Your code moves the form to the very top left corner  of the primary screen.  When i check the sp.y coordinate though it shows 31 after the move.  I was expecting 0 (since we just set Top = 0).  I'm guessing this means my caption bar is 31 pixels in height?

Comment: Also, i seem to have additional problem of multiple monitors.  I can use `Screen->Height` and `Screen->Width` to get info on this primary monitor, but i can't find the full width of my multi-monitor desktop.  Any ideas?

Comment: Yes, if I understand it correctly, if you do `Top=0` the form moves to the top and if you then check `sp.y` it'll point to the top pixel in your forms client area (31), that is right below the caption bar - but for some reason, `Left=0` positions the form slightly to the right of the edge and I reduced that with `sp.x` and got it placed correctly. This was with C++Builder 10.3 in Windows 10.

I now tried the same with 10.2.1 in W7 and there `Top=0; Left=0;` positions it perfectly @ Top/Left. I'm not sure where to put the blame. :-/

Comment: I haven't had the opportunity to play around with multiple monitors yet so I really don't know about that part.

Comment: Look at `Screen.Monitors` and `Screen.MonitorCount`, so it would be something like `Screen.Monitors[0].Width + Screen.Monitors[1].Width` (in Delphi anyway)

Comment: `Screen->DesktopRect` _Use DesktopRect to determine the coordinates of the entire virtual desktop, which includes all monitors in the system. DesktopRect is expressed in coordinates where (0,0) is the upper-left corner of the primary monitor. The primary monitor is the monitor with its Primary property set to true._

Comment: ...and `Screen->DisplayCount` helps to loop through the individual FMX displays ( `Screen->Displays[idx]` in C++). It's called `Monitors` in VCL though.

Comment: My `Screen->DesktopRect` description was for VCL. The FMX description for `Screen->DesktopRect` is _Gets the pixel parameters of the virtual screen's rectangle. A virtual screen refers to a multiple display system. The virtual screen is the bounding rectangle of all displays used to comprise the desktop._

Comment: Ted has me on the right track.  I'll use `Screen->DesktopWidth`, `Screen->DesktopLeft` to determine if i'm on the far right or left of the desktop (spanning multiple monitors if present).  That along with `Screen->DesktopTop` will let me know when i'm near either edge (left or right) or near top of the entire desktop.

Answer (score 0):

Based on input from Ted & David i put together the following code.  It will popup a message if the left edge of the form is close (within errX pixels) to the left edge of the desktop.  It will popup a message if the top edge of the forms client area is close (within errY pixels) to the top edge of the desktop.  Not pretty, but shows the idea.

```
void __fastcall TForm1::Button4Click(TObject *Sender)
{

int dWidth = Screen->DesktopWidth;
int dLeft = Screen->DesktopLeft;
int dRight = dWidth + dRight;  // deskLeft is 0 if primary monitor is most left monitor
int dTop = Screen->DesktopTop;
int errX = 10;  // within 10 pixels is fine enough
int errY = 40; // remember 30 or so pixels for caption bar
TPointF cli(0.0, 0.0);
TPointF sp = ClientToScreen(cli); //sp holds the coordinates for top left of form client area
ShowMessage("X = " + FloatToStr(sp.x) + "\nY = " + FloatToStr(sp.y));  //show coordinates of top/left of form client area

if (dLeft < 0) {  //negative value
 if ((abs(dLeft)-abs(sp.x)) < errX) {
  ShowMessage("Within " + IntToStr(errX) + " pixels of left edge."); // or further left of edge
 }
}
else {
 if ((dLeft + sp.x)< errX) {
  ShowMessage("Within " + IntToStr(errX) + " pixels of left edge."); // or further left of edge
 }
}

if (sp.x > 0) {  // no need to test the negative case
 if ((dRight-sp.x) < errX) {
  ShowMessage("Within " + IntToStr(errX) + " pixels of right edge."); // or further right of edge
 }
}

if ((dTop + sp.y)< errY) {
 ShowMessage("Within " + IntToStr(errY) + " pixels of top edge.");
}

}
```

This code works regardless of which monitor is primary.

UPDATE 1:  This code has problems when the monitors are not aligned along their top edge.  In the pic below monitors 1 & 3 have their tops aligned.  2 does not.  In this example DesktopTop returned -876.  So it seems that David's tip toward "Monitors" is the way to go - in C++ it is "Displays".  e.g.  `TRect myR = Screen->Displays[0].BoundsRect;` to get the rectangle of display 0 and then `int theTop = myR.top;` to find the top of this particular display.

[image]

thanks, russ

Comment: If you want to run this in a function then will need `TPointF sp = Form1->ClientToScreen(cli);` to get the scope correct for ClientToScreen.